# Custom 401 page in IIS with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have an internet facing ASP.NET website which I want to secure via Windows Authentication. I set my web.config file as:

```
<system.web>
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
 <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
    <deny users="?"/>        
 </authorization>
```

I have then disabled Anonymous Access and enabled Windows Authentication in IIS 7.5.

This results in the prompt box being displayed for my Windows credentials, however clicking 'Cancel' gives me a standard 401 error page. I would like to display a static HTML file in place of this message, however I've not been able to get it working and I've tried a combination of various settings such as:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" lockAllAttributesExcept="errorMode"> <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="c:\inetpub\custerr" path="MyCustom401.htm" /> </httpErrors>
```

and

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
    <error statusCode="401" redirect="MyCustom401.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

What I would like to happen is that anyone entering the correct Windows credentials can carry onto the website as normal, but those with invalid or details to see the custom HTML page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Web browsers usually show their versions of error pages, so do you really want to change the IIS ones?

Comment: I want to show a custom page to the user which will give instructions on how they can go about getting valid credentials to be able to log into the website. So yes, I want to be able to override the error page that they see.

Comment: That's simply impossible as the web browser side setting takes highest priority. You will have to redirect to specific page and return a 200 response code instead of 401.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to make sure is that you are allowing anonymous users access to the path where the error files are included otherwise they won't get the error page. For example here is a configuration file that should give you the intended results if your error files are in a directory (errors). First it disables anonymous access for all the site, but then opens it for the "errors" folder:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <error statusCode="401" subStatusCode="2" path="/errors/unauthorized.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>

    <location path="errors">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authorization>
                    <clear />
                    <add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
                </authorization>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This doesn't work when Windows Authentication (SSO) is enabled. It breaks the SSO and doesn't ask for authentication, instead directly shows the 401 page.