# Redirect to custom 401 page when "Access denied" occures within an ASP.NET application which is having Windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET application which is windows authenticated. When am accessing it from a different network it is throwing a 401 unauthorised error. For that I  have redirected the 401 unauthorised error to an anonymous error page. But this is now creating issue when we access it from the same network. Here also it is redirecting to the same anonymous page. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this solution?
[Custom 401 page in IIS with ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468174/custom-401-page-in-iis-with-asp-net)

Comment: Yes, I have. But it is redirecting me to the same error page even though I have windows identity